# Rsync multiple files and change names in target directory

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I want to rsync multiple files based on a file list and would like to also change the file names, I know this is possible with a normal rsync of just a single file, but not sure if it can be possible to do with multiple files.

**local_dir**

- local1.txt
- local2.txt
- local3.txt

**target_dir**

- target1.txt
- target2.txt
- target3.txt

File List contains a list of files of local_dir

I was trying to run the following command:

`rsync -avP --log-file=rsync.log --files-from file_list.txt local_dir data_host:remote_dir`

This creates a directory where it stores the multiple files with original file names.

Comment: "_I [...] would like to also change the file names_" - This isn't possible

Comment: @roaima Not with a single invocation of `rsync`, no.

Comment: I assume matching names are important for rsync to check what has been copied, so I doubt that this is at all possible... Is there a problem with using `rename` after the download?

Comment: I'm also using an executioner in the background, but I believe that using rename could be a subtle approach. Thanks :)